# How do I upgrade pear from 1.4.9 to the latest version?

Tags: installation, upgrade, pear

It looks like it might be `1.7.2`, but I didn't find any definitive, "THIS IS THE CURRENT VERSION OF PEAR" on the pear website.

I'm trying to upgrade PEAR on a system that I'm not all that familiar with.

pear version yields...

```
PEAR Version: 1.4.9
PHP Version: 5.1.6
Zend Engine Version: 2.1.0
Running on: Linux...
```

I ran `pear upgrade pear` and this message was included.

```
pear/PEAR dependency package "pear/Archive_Tar" installed version 1.3.5 is not the recommended version 1.3.3, but may be compatible, use --force to install
pear/Archive_Tar requires PEAR Installer (version >= 1.5.4), installed version is 1.4.9
```

Comment: I know how you feel; PEAR and PECL have always been kind sloppy. It's even worse for Windows. `:-(`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

pear upgrade --force http://pear.php.net/get/PEAR-1.9.0

Answer (score 8):

It's now

```
pear upgrade --force --alldeps http://pear.php.net/get/PEAR-1.10.1
```

Then upgrade the rest

```
pear clear-cache
pear update-channels
pear upgrade
pear upgrade-all
```

Comment: Using this returns a warning saying to use `pear channel-update pear.php.net`

Answer (score 2):

I am using Debian 8 and apt-get install php-pear only installs 1.9.

I then found this works:

pear upgrade pear

Answer (score 1):

The current stable version [appears to be 1.9.0](http://pear.php.net/package/PEAR).